# Migrate from SharePoint server to Office365

Tags: office-365, migration

I will need to do a migration from SharePoint Server 2007 to Office 365. They have a small intranet today with only a couple of lists and libraries (approximately 1000 documents) What is the best solution?

And what is the new features etc compared to SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 1):

You did not bother to [search](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=migration%20from%20SharePoint%20Server%202007%20to%20Office%20365.&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enBD645BD645&oq=migration%20from%20SharePoint%20Server%202007%20to%20Office%20365.&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

**Free solution:**

- [How to Migrate SharePoint 2007 to Office 365 Standard Using Native
  Web Service and CSOM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/himanshukumar/archive/2012/05/22/how-to-migrate-sharepoint-2007-to-office-365-standard-using-native-web-service-and-csom.aspx)

**Paid Solution:**

- [Migrate from SharePoint 2007 to Office 365 with Sharegate](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/migrate-sharepoint-2007-to-office-365-with-sharegate)

Answer (score 1):

I found one more paid solution with multiple option Supports Multiple Migrations with four different modes:

- SharePoint to SharePoint Migration
- SharePoint to Office 365 Migration
- Office 365 to SharePoint Migration
- Office 365 to Office 365 Migration

If you are looking for Paid then may be it will help you : http://www.systoolsgroup.com/sharepoint-organiser.html